# Scrape Excel formulas from cells

Tags: excel, vba

For documentation purposes, I want to catalog all formulas within a worksheet. How would I go about it in VBA?

Show the VBA used to loop through all cells in a worksheet and copy only the formulas to another list.

Answer (score 1):

The [Range.SpecialCells method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx) has `xlCellTypeFormula` as one of the [xlCellType constants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836534.aspx) to look for. That may significantly reduce the cells to cycle through as opposed to using the [Range .HasFormula property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837123.aspx) or the [Range.Find method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx) looking for `=*` within the [UsedRange property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa215923%28v=office.11%29.aspx).

```
Option Explicit

Sub enumFormulas()
    Dim f As Long, w As Long, ws As Worksheet
    Dim fws As String, rng As Range, allFormulas As Range
    Dim vPROPs As Variant

    On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
    appTGGL
    fws = "Formulas"

    On Error GoTo bm_New_List_ws
    Set ws = Sheets(fws)
    On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
    For w = 1 To Worksheets.Count
        With Worksheets(w)
            If LCase(.Name) = LCase(fws) Then GoTo bm_Next_ws
            On Error Resume Next
            Set allFormulas = .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 23)
            On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit

            If Not allFormulas Is Nothing Then
                For Each rng In allFormulas
                    With rng
                        vPROPs = Array(.Parent.Name, _
                                       .Address(0, 0), _
                                       .Value, _
                                       .Value2, _
                                       .Text, _
                                       .Formula, _
                                       .FormulaR1C1, _
                                       .NumberFormat)
                    End With
                    With ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp) _
                      .Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, UBound(vPROPs))
                        .NumberFormat = "@"
                        .Offset(0, 2).Resize(1, 1).NumberFormat = vPROPs(UBound(vPROPs))
                        .Offset(0, 3).Resize(1, 1).NumberFormat = "General"
                        .Value2 = vPROPs
                    End With
                Next
            End If
bm_Next_ws:
        End With
    Next w

GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
bm_New_List_ws:
    If Err.Number = 9 Then
        vPROPs = Array("Worksheet", ",Address", ".Value", ".Value2", ".Text", ".Formula", ".FormulaR1C1")
        Worksheets.Add after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        With Sheets(Sheets.Count)
            .Name = fws
            .Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(vPROPs) + 1) = vPROPs
        End With
        Resume
    End If
bm_Safe_Exit:
    appTGGL
End Sub

Sub appTGGL(Optional bTGGL As Boolean = True)
    Application.Calculation = IIf(bTGGL, xlCalculationAutomatic, xlCalculationManual)
    Application.EnableEvents = bTGGL
    Application.DisplayAlerts = bTGGL
    Application.ScreenUpdating = bTGGL
    Application.Cursor = IIf(bTGGL, xlDefault, xlWait)
End Sub
```

The [Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx) with its [Range.Cells property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273.aspx) have numerous properties and other valid information for documenting a [Worksheet object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224506(v=office.11).aspx) or a [Worksheets collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224508(v=office.11).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on the type of output wanted.

For starters, it is possible to expose all formulas by converting all fields to text format. (Try this on a copy of the document so you don't have to rely on the UNDO command to revert things back to their original format.)

Another approach is to create a worksheet in Excel containing the Source worksheet name, cell address, and formula, in three separate columns.

```
Public Sub ListFormulas()

  Dim sWS As Worksheet
  Dim tWS As Worksheet
  Dim lRow As Long
  Dim aCell As Range

  With ActiveWorkbook
    Set sWS = .Sheets("BiosList 2.16")   'SourceWorksheetName
    Set tWS = .Sheets("Junk")    '*** i.e. where the list will be created  TargetWorksheetName

  End With

  With tWS
    .Range("A1").Value = "Source Worksheet"
    .Range("B1").Value = "Cell Address"
    .Range("C1").Value = "Formula"
  End With

  lRow = 2    '*** Start target list in row 2

  For Each aCell In sWS.UsedRange
    If Left(aCell.Formula, 1) = "=" Then
      With tWS
        .Range("A" & lRow).Value = sWS.Name
        .Range("B" & lRow).Value = aCell.Address
        .Range("C" & lRow).Value = "'" & aCell.Formula
      End With
      lRow = lRow + 1
    End If
  Next aCell
  MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

Comment: The [Range.SpecialCells method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx) has `xlCellTypeFormula` as one of the [xlCellType constants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836534.aspx) to look for. That may significantly reduce the cells to cycle through.

Answer (score 0):

You just want to see the formulas as opposed to the result?

```
CTRL-`
```

(Key under the esc key on the keyboard, to the left of 1) cycles between formula and result view in a worksheet.